# How to send data to another activity from dynamically added EditTexts in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I've added a linear layout with id `layoutToExpend` and a button with id `buttonToAdd` in my activity_main.xml. I created another layout, layout_to_copy.xml where the EditText is defined which will be added on button click in the main activity inside `layoutToExpend`.

So here is my code in the MainActivity.java,

```
butttonToAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                
        View newEditTexts = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_to_copy,null,false);
        layoutToExpend.addView(newEditTexts);
                
    }
});
```

with this code whenever I click the button a new EditText is added. Now I want to write something in the added EditTexts and show them in a TextView in a new activity (Suppose, by clicking a new button `Send Data`.

How to do that could anyone kindly explain, I'm new to android studio and java.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a nice approach, try using recyclerview but if you don't want to use it then  whenever you are leaving the current activity A say on a button click then try run a for loop on linearlayout child items like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) v;
    for(int i = 0; i < l.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        /* now get the edittext object by using getChiltAt(i)
        and get the text from it*/
    }
}
```

Now you get the values in those edittext and append in any string and pass it in bundle to next activity.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for you comment. I really appreciate it. Btw, could you kindly please explain what to do inside the for loop, i'm really a noob in these.  And can i do exaxrly the same thing with recyclerview? i'd try learning it then.

Comment: if you don't know about recyclerview then better go for it first, here is the doc :https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?gclid=Cj0KCQjwjo2JBhCRARIsAFG667U8Q1SLBy73H9BiGhuQqfv56I2wb02WTgLX-gZao2mQaRexYn1tazUaAgTxEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Sample app: https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/RecyclerViewKotlin/

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem in a couple of ways. From the moment that you don't have a static amount of data source, you need to use an ArrayList or something similar. You didn't specified, so I'll assume that all the data that you have is of type String.

First of all, you have to declare the ArrayList, like this:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now that you declared the list, you have to populate it. You can do it this way:

```
arrayList.add("New entry");
```

Now you have to pass the data between activity. For this, there are quite a few ways to do it. You have to choose the right way for you, here I'm going to show you two different ways, for two different cases. Please note that all the following solutions don't implement persistent data, so you'll lost every data when you close your app.

1. If you need to access those data in more than one activity and in different moments, you can create an object and access it whenever you need.
   Here an example:

```
public class YourDataManager{

    private ArrayList<String> dataArrayList;
    private static YourDataManager instance;

    public YourDataManager(ArrayList<String> dataList){
        instance = this;
        dataArrayList = dataList;
    }


    public static YourDataManager getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public List<String> getData(){
        return dataArrayList;
    }

}
```

Now, in order to SET data, you have to do this:

```
//Where you have to set data. Assumed that the ArrayList with the data is already defined and populated. The name of that ArrayList from now on will be arrayList 
YourDataManager dataManager = new YourDataManager(arrayList);
```

Now, to retrieve the data stored in YourDataManager, do the following:

```
//Retrieve data from YourDataManager

ArrayList<String> savedArrayList = YourDataManager.getInstance().getData();

//Now you have the arrayList
```

2. The second method is similar to sending data using the intent. The limitation of this method is that you don't have it saved and accessible everywhere from your app. For this method, however, I'll redirect you to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents) answer.

Comment: a huge thanks to you❤️.  i learned lots of things from your answer. Helped a lot. btw, i think i'd try learning recyclerview as @sak said in another answer

Answer (score 1):

For taking the value from edit text. there is a couple of ways.

1/ If your edit text is limited. like user can add 5 edit text by tapping the add button. then you can create 5 edit texts in your XML layour file. and make their visibility "gone". every time you tap the add button one edit text will be visible.
so now you can define their id and take value by those ids.

2/ If your edit text is unlimited. then you can use a recycler view to add new edit text. so now you have the position id of the new edit text item by which you can get the value of edit text.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd start learning recyclerview

Comment: you are welcome. If you need any help, you know how to find me